# How to create separate results with a single nagios check?

Tags: nagios

I've written a check for our Nagios to find offline AccessPoints. This one check will test all 400 APs at one turn, which is also very efficient, but there is one drawback: If some of the APs will be offline for a while and i know, there is no way to get rid of the critical-error in Nagios. If i acknowledge the service to a time when i expect the APs o work again, i will not see other APs fail.

Now, i wonder if there is a way to check all APs in one turn, but to create separate check-results in Nagios, so i could only ACK the ones which i know they're out-of-order for a while. I don't think do a check for each AP is a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

A check for each AP is the easiest and cleanest way to do this. Then you can have a metacheck that alerts on the conditions you give to it.

Another approach is using a temp file to store the current status and a config file where you pseudo-ack the APs. the meta-check would only need to compare those two files.

In our Icinga (nagios-fork) installation we have something on these lines. I wrote a php frontend for it, the action note link brings me to a page where I can edit graphically the parameters for the checks.